# How To Highlight a Column in a WinForm StackedColumn Chart

Tags: winforms, charts

I'd like to highlight a single column in a WinForm StackedColumn Chart.  As examples, I'm seeing how to put borders around the individual DataPoints in each Series displayed in the column and put an ArrowAnnotation pointing at one of the DataPoints, but I don’t see a way to highlight the column as a whole.  For example, it would be great to have the column expand to say twice the width of the other columns and/or have a different backcolor (including the empty areas above and below the DataPoints).  Is it possible to do what I want and, if so, how?  C# examples are preferable but not necessary.
Thanks.  Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dim every other column, using `BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.Percent50` and `BackSecondaryColor = Color.Black`.  This will make your chosen column appear brighter/highlighted.

Here's an example:

```
int highlightColumnIndex = 0; // Set the highlighted column here!
foreach (Series cs in chart1.Series) {
    foreach (DataPoint dp in cs.Points) {
        dp.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Black;
        dp.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.Percent50;
    }
    cs.Points[highlightColumnIndex].BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
}
```

Change `chart1` to your chart's name, and change `highlightColumnIndex` to match the index of the column you want to highlight.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow.  Great suggestion.  I missed the whole Percent option.  This will really help me accomplish my objective.  Thanks.